# Asynchronous images - Meant for displaying images from web only?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have images in my documents folder which I am displaying on one of my screens. It takes times to load the images and display them on the screen similar to when loading images from web. As far as I know asynchronous imageView works for the later case. I might be wrong.

Is there anyway we can display images from documents folder asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/). It is a UIImageView subclass that lets you display image asynchronously from a URL and with a useful cache. It is designed to work with Internet URLs, but I think it will also go with internal URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Put the loading of images in the background thread as following

```
-(void)backgroundLoadImageFromPath:(NSString*)path {
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [myImageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:newImage waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Then call that thread wherever you need to set the image

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundLoadImageFromPath:) withObject:path];
```

Note, in backgroundLoadImageFromPath you need to wait until the setImage: selector finishes, otherwise the background thread's autorelease pool may deallocate the image before the setImage: method can retain it.